# What is the RegEx for this match?

Tags: regex, vb.net, lookbehind, quantifiers

I am trying to match the number before the semicolon but I can't use a quantifier in my lookbehind so I have no idea how to make this work.

The string (yes, there are tab spaces in between "item[##]" and "=")

```
<script language="javascript">
item[19]    = 13;
item[14]    = 13;
item[17]    = 7;
item[1] = 2;
</script>
```

I'd like to get the 13, 13, 7, and 2

This is my current RegEx, which obviously does not work:

```
(?<=item\[[0-9]).*?(?=;)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get it at matched group 1 that is captured by using parenthesis `()`

String literals for use in programs:

```
@"item\[\d+\].*?=\s+(\d+);"
```

Tested it [here](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx)

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly. To any passerby, I used System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match.Groups(1).Value to return the numbers I was looking for!

Comment: Short and sweet, +1 :)